# How to divide a row by the contents of the previous row with using loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using a pandas DataFrame, I would like to take every ith row and divide it by the i-1th row.  I would like to use vectorization (i.e., no for loops).

e.g.  If I have the following DataFrame:

```
1      10  
2      20  
8      160  
32     480
```

I would end up with:

```
1      10   
2       2   
4       8  
4       3
```

N.B.  The division operations use the old table values, not the updated ones.

P.S.  Sorry about the bad formatting!

Comment: Here's a good table formatter! https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Very useful - I am sure I will use that a lot now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use, `div`, `shift`, and `fillna`:

```
df.div(df.shift(1)).fillna(df).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2   2
2  4   8
3  4   3
```